# error: Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_439_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, digital-ocean

My site is broken, from last few days I'm continuously getting mysql error.
In starting I was receiving this error almost everyday, which was fixed by doing some changes in  `my.cnf` file.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

But from last few days I am receiving this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_439_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)
>   Solution I tried:

- changed `tmp` directory permission to `777`
- add `tmpdir=/tmp` to my.cnf under [mysqld]
- `sudo reboot` (Temp fix)

I'm afraid to reinstall mysql, as these things are new for me and I don't want to loose any data. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What host are you using ? XAMPP, WampServer, EasyPHP, ...
You simply don't have the right permissions, go check `httpd.conf` file

Comment: You have wrong permissions on mysql data directory.

Comment: @jens File permission is set to 755  (/var/lib/mysql/)

Comment: @Hearner I am using apache server, Ubuntu 14.04 x64 on digitalocean.com cloud hosting. I tried to locate httpd.conf file via command, but I received this file /etc/phpmyadmin/lighttpd.conf which has 644 permission. Kindly clarify if I need to check something else.

Comment: OS error code  28:  No space left on device

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've checked space using command df -h 
It is showing 71% in use.
Do I need to increase space?

Comment: The percentage is not as relevant as actual byte count: if you need to store 500MB and have 400MB free you're out of luck even if those 400MB represent 99% of the partition. Whatever, contents of the `/tmp` directory are likely to change across time—it might be just a transitory issue.

Comment: Hi guys, I've increased droplet size, but again after few days it's giving same error. After troubleshoot I found I'm running out of inodes using 100%. Is there anything I can do to free some space? Please help